# Source references to resource files in layout section of *.qgs

Tags: qgis, qgs, qgz

I'm making a plugin that moves each resource into a custom folder structure (SHP, RASTER, ETC) and updates the paths within the qgs file.
In the layout section there are also references to resource files, which may be a repetition. Why is this? Is it really necessary?
[image]

Comment: there is also <datasource> with the same information

Comment: My guess would be for retro-compatibility with an older/different version of QGIS that might have needed the info there. Or each location *can* take different sources if they are compatible (or the same one), not sure.